# How to Zip files on Storage with ADF

Tags: azure-storage, azure-data-factory

Would there be a way to Zip/copy files on a blob-storage into another storage/folder but with a zipped result ?
You can deflate with ADF, but can you enflate ?
We receive +100k files a day, the next day I would like to zip them all into a archive folder.
Couldn't find a way ...
So any help/.hints appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADF supports zipdeflate format, which can archive multiple files into a single zip file. Refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs#compression-support.

Comment: Silly me. I thought that ZipDeflate only meant to Unzip and that there would we a ZipENflate needed. Works like a charm !